# Laravel is creating routes incorrectly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I made this route:

```php
Route::resource('questionnaire_correction/{id}', QuestionnaireCorrectionController::class)->only(['create', 'store']);
```

Using this route, I get `Route [questionnaire_correction.create] not defined.`.

Checking the routes with `php artisan r:l --path=quesionnaire` I get:

```bash
POST            questionnaire_correction/{questionnaireid} .................... {questionnaireid}.store › QuestionnaireCorrectionController@store
GET|HEAD        questionnaire_correction/{questionnaireid}/create ............. {questionnaireid}.create › QuestionnaireCorrectionController@create
```

Somehow, it is creating the route name `{questionnaireid}.store`. I am using Laravel 10.

Creating the routes like this works:

```php
Route::get('/questionnaire_correction/{questionnaireid}', [QuestionnaireCorrectionController::class, 'create'])->name('questionnaire_correction.create');
Route::post('/questionnaire_correction/{questionnaireid}', [QuestionnaireCorrectionController::class, 'store'])->name('questionnaire_correction.store');
```

Comment: Please change the  {id} to {questionnaireid} in the resource routes. It's solved your problem.

Comment: neither `questionnaire`, `questionnaireid`, nor `questionnionaire_id` change the route name

Comment: Why are you passing model to create and store routes. In Resource route specefiction there is no need for a model because we don't create it yet. Removing {id} can the problem but you won't be able to inject model data.

Comment: It's a nested resource. Create route for example creates not only a correction, it is creating a correction *for a questionnaire*, so the controller needs the questionnaire on every method.

Comment: Then try Route::resource('questionnaire.correction')

Comment: The names for the resource route will be questionnaire.correction.store and questionnaire.correction.create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the names for each route like this:

```
Route::resource('questionnaire_correction/{id}', 
App\Http\Controllers\QuestionnaireCorrectionController::class, [
'names' => [ 
    'create' => 'questionnaire_correction.create', 
    'store' => 'questionnaire_correction.store', 
])->only(['create', 'store']);
```